# Mapping JSON from URL with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

[image]I'm parsing a JSON string from url. From this URL I want to map only a certain array of Items so I parse it using **Jackson**.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(new URL(urls.get(i)), Map.class);
```

... and now my `Hashmap` contains this key set:

```
 [status,count,pages,category,posts]
```

`posts` is an `array` of `Object`s that I have already defined a mapping `class`.

So When I try to parse them like this:

```
post[] posts= mapper.readValue(map.get("posts").toString(),post[].class);
```

I get this `Exception`:

```
Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

From what I understand when I perform the first mapping it takes away the `"` that the field of a JSON string should have.

What can I do to overcome this ?

Comment: I recommend displaying the JSON you're parsing in your answer.

Comment: @Mena posting the whole JSON String from the url wouldn't help, here is the String after been parsed by online JSON  viewer. You can See that the 'i' is from the first field id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a design problem, and are addressing it the wrong way.

1. You should de-serialize your JSON as a custom Object instead of a
   `Maps<String, Object>`. This would allow to leverage the OO features of your instance instead of accessing the properties through casting (which you are not doing, see point 2).
2. To solve your immediate problem, you cannot de-serialize from a non-JSON `Object`, which is what you're trying to do when you assign `posts` a value. Instead, try something in the lines of:

   ```
   Post[] posts = (Post[])map.get("posts");
   ```

Comment: ok I've gave it a try with something like ArrayList<Post> posts=(ArrayList<Post>) map.get("posts"); and it gives me the correct size of posts. However isn't mapped correctly, I mean When I try to post.get(i).getTitle() i get an exception .ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap. How can I use the first step?

Comment: @libathos you can try to cast the `Object` you get as `Post` again, but it's only delaying the issue. See my point 1.

Comment: I've tried this         Map<String,posts[]> map = mapper.readValue(new URL(urls.get(i)), Map.class); but it didn't work correctly shouldn't this only parse the posts-part of the JSON?

Comment: post is my custom Object I've written it and only contains some of the field the post objects contain on the server side

Comment: @libathos I know you have a custom `Post` object. I'm talking about the object you're de-serializing the JSON to. One of this object's properties will be a `Collection<Post>` called `posts`.

Comment: Ooh Ok, I'll try it and let you know